# filter dictionary for required key values in python

Tags: python

how to filter required  key values in python, where as dict has a list in its every key value.

ex: `{a:[1, 2, 3, 4], b:[2,3,4,5], c:[1,2,3], .......}`

I have tried the following snippet:

```
values = self.get_json_metrics_and_filter_data()
values = [x.get(values_key_name) for x in values]
```

I'm dynamically passing the "values_key_name".

My main concern here in the snippet is "get" method not working...

```
[x.get(values_key_name) for x in values]
```

and getting following error "'str' object has no attribute 'get'"

Please help Thanks

Comment: `values` is a list that has strings in it, and string object doesn't have `get` method, exactly as the error message indicates.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Step 1 of debugging: Read the error message. Step 2 of debugging: Read the error message again, because you obviously didn't understand what it was saying the first time.

Comment: Hint: `get` is a `dict` method, and `x` is **not** a `dict`.

Comment: Thank you all! @MarounMaroun.

Comment: thank you @gtlambert, Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams and PM 2Ring  for all your support !  i have tried the other way its working now.                                             As suggested by PM 2ring i was getting only a single list str, it helped me, and also Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams for your support the answer is [values.get(values_key_name)]